# Can a infinite group be a finite union of proper subgroups?

Tags: group-theory

We know that a group can not be written as a union of two proper subgroups and obiously a finite group can be written as a finite union of proper subgroups.So I want to ask if a infinite group be written as a finite union of proper subgroups?Moveover,Can a field be a finite union of proper subfields?

Comment: How are you going to write $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ as a union of **proper** subgroups?

Comment: Or $\mathbb Z$, for that matter.

Answer (score 13):

Sometimes an infinite group can be written as a finite union of proper subgroups, e.g., every element of ${\bf Z}\oplus{\bf Z}$ is of at least one of the forms $(2a,b)$, $(a,2b)$, or $(a+b,a-b)$ for integers $a,b$, and that gives you 3 proper subgroups whose union is the whole group.

As for fields, note that a field and its subfields are all vector spaces over the prime field, so if a vector space can't be a finite union of proper subspaces, then a field can't be a finite union of proper subfields. The vector space question for infinite fields is handled [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26/can-a-vector-space-over-an-infinite-field-be-a-finite-union-of-proper-subspaces). For finite fields, it's easy to see the answer is no. That leaves infinite fields of finite characteristic to think about.

Comment: Complete answer!

Comment: As a side note, it can be shown that a group $G$ can be written as the union of three proper subgroups if and only if it has $H = \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ as a quotient, in which case the three subgroups in question are the inverse images (under the quotient map from $G$ to $H$) of the three two-element subgroups of $H$. Gerry's example fits this characterization.

Answer (score 9):

There is a lot of research on groups *covered* by a finite set of proper subgroups. It all started with a seminal paper of Bernhard Neumann, *Groups covered by finitely many cosets*, Publ. Math. Debrecen 3 (1954), 227-242, in which he proves that if a group is the union of a finite number of subgroups (or even cosets), you only have to take into account those subgroups having finite index. This implies that a group has a finite covering by subgroups if and only if it has a finite non-cyclic homomorphic image. See also [recent work of Mira Bhargava](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/MiraBhargava07.pdf), the mother of the brilliant number theorist Manjul Bhargava.

Comment: Is it also true that any way of writing a group as a proper union of subgroups union is the pullback of a way of writing a finite group as a proper union of subgroups  along an epimorphism onto the finite group?

Answer (score 6):

As you say, obviously a finite (noncyclic!) group $G$ can be written as a finite union of proper subgroups - call them $G_1,\dots,G_f$. Now let $H$ be any infinite group. The direct product $G\times H$ can then be written as a finite union of the proper subgroups $G_1\times H,\dots,G_f\times H$.